# PayPal RestApi Identity Service For Asp.net C# Not Returning correct url

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I am currently trying to implement PayPal login on our clients site to be able to integrate seamless checkout. I have a link to the documentation on how to do it here:

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid

After implementing this I noticed that even if I pass in the mode as sandbox, it still gives me a live url. Also, the client id comes back empty (I'm guessing b/c the client id I'm using is only for testing).

How can I force the api to return a sandbox/testing url?

Answer (score 0):

just create simple example,like take one button on the form and in code behind file put 
following code in the button click event:

```
        string business = "here type your email id";
        string itemName = "Plan1"; //this variable for itemname.
        double itemAmount = 8.00;// this variable for itemprice.
        string currencyCode = "USD";  //this variable for currency code.

        StringBuilder ppHref = new StringBuilder();

        ppHref.Append("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick");
        ppHref.Append("&business=" + business);
        ppHref.Append("&item_name=" + itemName);
        ppHref.Append("&amount=" + itemAmount.ToString("#.00"));
        ppHref.Append("&currency_code=" + currencyCode);

        Response.Redirect(ppHref.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: I'm confused, I asked about the ability to sign into paypal from our site. That is what the PayPal Identity service offers.